# Evaluate $-\gamma-W_{-1}\left(-\gamma e^{-\gamma}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$ in $\gamma$.

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions, closed-form

Evaluate $\gamma$ expressed, involving Lambert function, by
$$-\gamma-W_{-1}\left(-\gamma e^{-\gamma}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$ where $\gamma<1$. I doubt that it is possible to find a value for $\gamma$ in closed form. Numerical solutions or estimates are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact expression for the solution is: $$\gamma=\frac{\pi/4}{e^{\pi/4}-1}=0.6581842...$$

**EDIT**
The two branches are related in a trascendental way. Their difference can be used to solve other trascendental equations.

If $y(x)=\frac{x}{1-e^x}$

then :

$x=W_0(ye^y)-W_{-1}(ye^y)=y-W_{-1}(ye^y)$ for  $-1< x <0 $

$x=W_{-1}(ye^y)-W_{0}(ye^y)=y-W_{0}(ye^y)$ for  $x < -1 $

See

http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/SYNASC2014.pdf

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195923/equation-between-the-two-branches-of-the-lambert-w-function

Comment: And how did you get this?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95742/what-is-the-name-of-fracez-1z-and-how-to-invert-it/196389#196389

Answer (score 1):

$$\gamma\simeq0.658184273600902103771558680728257154392531172950\ldots$$

Comment: Good, Mathematica?